# Does Python's enum class use partial string matching?

Tags: python-3.x, string, enums, string-matching

I have an enum class representing time periods, but i'd like the have two different names for the same mapping

```
class TimePeriod(enum.IntEnum):
    DAILY = 1
    MONTH = 2
    MONTHLY = 2
```

However, when I access MONTH or MONTHLY I get the MONTH type as shown below:

```
TimePeriod.MONTH
returns: <TimePeriod.MONTH: 2>

TimePeriod.MONTHLY
returns: <TimePeriod.MONTH: 2>
```

Is Python's enum code using partial matching for the enumeration?
This happens when I reverse the order of MONTH and MONTHLY in the class definition as well.

Comment: you need to only define one per value....so use either `month` or `monthly` but not both

Comment: "This happens when I reverse the order of MONTH and MONTHLY in the class definition as well." In my tests it does not. The first definition wins.

Comment: You can easily check that it's not using a partial match by "accessing" ``TimePeriod.MONTHL``.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are unique -- not by name, but by value.  When a name for a value appears more than once, the name first seen is considered the canonical name for that value, and all other names for that same value are aliases.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values):

Having two enum members with the same name is invalid:

```
>>>
>>> class Shape(Enum):
...     SQUARE = 2
...     SQUARE = 3
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: Attempted to reuse key: 'SQUARE'
However, two enum members are allowed to have the same value.
Given two members A and B with the same value (and A defined
first), B is an alias to A. By-value lookup of the value of A
and B will return A. By-name lookup of B will also return A:

>>>
>>> class Shape(Enum):
...     SQUARE = 2
...     DIAMOND = 1
...     CIRCLE = 3
...     ALIAS_FOR_SQUARE = 2
...
>>> Shape.SQUARE
<Shape.SQUARE: 2>
>>> Shape.ALIAS_FOR_SQUARE
<Shape.SQUARE: 2>
>>> Shape(2)
<Shape.SQUARE: 2>
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.